# Is it possible use Phone number for the login in firebase ?

Tags: firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication

I am new to firebase. I am trying to create my ionic2 hybrid app. where I am using firebase for back-end. As per the firebase Sign-in providers the option available as below.

[image]

I wanted to create login based on mobile number. For the registration I will as to enter mobile number & send verification code. Once the verification code verified user can login and access the application.

Can you please let me know is this possible in firebase. And how we can achieve this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to have mobile number based login in Firebase.

Comment: Thanks Pankaj...... Is there any alternative option or any other workaround/solution for achieving this functionality?

Comment: You can build the functionality around firebase. 

http://blog.parse.com/announcements/phone-based-login-can-you-dig-it/

though repository is not active but you can get the idea from https://github.com/danglade/AnyPhone

Comment: Though I didn't think of user creation on Firebase with Mobile phone numbers, it sounds good.

I would try to come up with some basic solutions.

keep watching the space http://time2hack.com/tag/firebase

Comment: You can take example from https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/account-verification-node to build your own account verification with twilio.